# Form Validation event issue

Tags: javascript, forms

So I'm trying to write an interactive form, where clicking a radio button will unhide another field in the form. It is for display purpose, so I'm not submitting anything. I'm attempting to use Javascript to validate, but needless to say, it's not working very well. A run through of my code would be appreciated.

Since it's so much code, I'll pastie it to you for convenience... 
http://pastie.org/3615669

Thanks :)

Comment: Please ask a "real question" where is your problem? **just pasting  "so much code- HELP!" isn't a good question**, which causes bad answers\ close question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I try to be as clear as I can, but sometimes it can be difficult to limit an entire script to one statement... I will keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
function getShrimpa(radio, name, ext){
    //Use of form 'shrimpa'. 
    var form = document.shrimpa;  

    document.form.name.style.display = 'block'; // <---- this is not valid
    document.getElementById('shrimpa').innerHTML = ext;  
}
```

You cannot use the variable `name` like that. It's a string and it will not get "replaced" or whatever you were hoping would happen. You'll need to use `document.getElementsByName(name)` to select that element. But that will give you a node list so you probably want to use ids instead there.